# How can I implement help button in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

[image]

I just wonder how I can implement this button in the picture as python code. If I'm using QDialog as a base class. How can I access these button(including close button in case that I would like to reimplement it to minimize the main window instead)

So sorry if this made some confusion. I meant that I want to overwrite this button in my code. For example, if I want to overwrite this close button I have to rewrite close event, right? How can I overwrite help event? Do they have any help event? Sorry if this question seems like a real noob, to be honest, I'm really noob for programming.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain yourself better

Comment: Try to set your dialog window flags to `dialog.setWindowsFlags(Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint | (rest of your current flags)`

Comment: Actually, I meant to implement functions to them not just set it straight. I've already known how to remove it, but I don't know how I can overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still find this helpful, when the '?' button is clicked, the event triggered is EnterWhatsThisMode. This works:

```py
def event(self, event): 
    if event.type() == QEvent.EnterWhatsThisMode: #Event called when ? is clicked                
        QWhatsThis.leaveWhatsThisMode() #To change mouse cursor back to arrow
        #Any other code you want could go here
        return True
    return QtGui.QDialog.event(self, event)
```